# ClamAV exclude on some signature does not work

Tags: clamav

I use ClamAV with 3rd party signature. So, in order to exclude some virus signature from scanning, I followed the official documentation to add a new .ign2 file like below:

```
cd /usr/local/share/clamav/
touch whitelist.ign2
chmod 644 whitelist.ign2
```

When doing the scan I got a false positive signature like this:

```
/mysql/mysql_backups-02-08-2020_04-30-01/databasedbs.sql.gz: YARA.eval_post.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
```

So, I included the signature like this in the `whitelist.ign2`. Here are some of other exclude signatures:

```
$ cat /usr/local/share/clamav/whitelist.ign2
{HEX}Malware.Expert.generic.eval.post.2
{HEX}php.malware.magento.594
{HEX}Malware.Expert.malware.url.hastebin.com.0
{multi}Malware.Expert.wget.curl.lwp-download.exec.system.signature
YARA.php_malware_hexinject
YARA.shankar_php_php
YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php
{HEX}Malware.Expert.generic.eval.gzinflate.base64.9
{HEX}Malware.Expert.generic.malware.127
YARA.r57shell_php_php
YARA.eval_post
```

From my tests, some signature are excluded like

```
{HEX}php.malware.magento.594, {HEX}Malware.Expert.generic.eval.post.2
```

but some signatures are not excluded and still found by clamav eventhough I have included in the excluded list example:

```
YARA.eval_post, YARA.r57shell_php_php
```

Anyone experience this problem ? What do you do to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.
Solution for this is adding just `eval_post` to whitelist.ign2
and restart service)

Comment: I'll try this, and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with all YARA signatures and found the solution for this. So, for all YARA-based signatures, when you want to exclude the rule do not put the `YARA` keyword:

For example, this is a false positive infection found by clamAV:

```
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/File-Listing-6.15.tar.gz: YARA.blackhole2_htm11.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
```

To whitelist the above signature just put this in your .ign2 whitelist file:

```
blackhole2_htm11
```

No need to put the keyword `YARA` and `UNOFFICIAL`